# Next steps after Setuptools integration using Click

Tags: python, command-line, setuptools, python-click

In our project, we are using [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/) to create command-line interfaces. We have a folder called `foo` in the project, and `__main__.py` file there contains `Click.group` definition.

For now, we can access the cli using -

```
python foo [OPTIONS]
```

but, we wish to simplify it to just -

```
foo [OPTIONS]
```

I had a look at [Setuptools integration using Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/setuptools/), and I was successful in creating command after following the instructions. But, what steps are to be done next is unclear to me.

1. After I introduce `setup.py` to the project, do I need to ask everyone using the project to run `pip install --editable .`?
2. What happens if someone adds new commands/options in the project? Will all users again need to run `pip` commands?
3. The project will always run in UNIX environment and we are wondering if there exists a shebang-way of running `foo/__main__.py` with just `foo`. If we had `foo` (not foo.py) as file containing Click.group definition, adding a shebang at the top of file would remove the need to use python while invoking commands.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install --editable .` means that if you manipulate the files inside the package, it will have immediately an effect when you use the package in Python, because `import yourpackagename` will refer to the folder with the original package.

`pip install .` will copy the package folder into some other path and use that when you use `import yourpackagename`, so any modifications to the original package files will not have an effect until you reinstall it.